# Match a string that could have a newline anywhere in it in - bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a string containing a number that is represented as follows:

```
\S2=number_goes_here\
```

The number could be anything from `0.00000` and up.  However, there could be a newline anywhere in that string, and I am not entirely sure how to go about matching that.  Ultimately, I just want the number from this.  Importantly, this string is amidst a large chunk of text that can be represented by this sample (`S2` is found on the last line there):

```
 1.454187\H,0,0.719618,3.525801,1.633708\H,0,-0.454651,2.80328,2.23844\
 Ru,0,0.025774,1.557599,-0.253913\\Version=EM64L-G09RevD.01\State=6-A\H
 F=-1238.5377983\S2=8.75446\S2-1=0.\S2A=8.750006\RMSD=2.314e-09\Dipole=
```

I'm open to bash, sed, awk, gawk; whatever thoughts you have to address this.

EDIT:

Here is example, the first answer below does not seem to have worked correctly for this example.  It only prints "2."

```
 .631441,-2.132979\H,0,0.20151,-1.464802,-2.95553\H,0,0.377883,-2.50668
 5,-1.874761\\Version=EM64L-G09RevD.01\State=3-A\HF=-1265.9035096\S2=2.
 053325\S2-1=0.\S2A=2.000966\RMSD=1.590e-04\Dipole=0.7197616,-2.1253769
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -Po '(?<=S2=)[\d.]+' <(tr -d '\n' < file)
```

gives

```
8.75446
```

Comment: +1; OSX users (where `grep` doesn't support `-P` - and therefore no lookarounds are supported - and `\d` can't be used inside sets): `egrep -o '\\S2=[0-9.]+' <(tr -d '\n' < file) | cut -d'=' -f2`

Comment: @mklement0 I tried this, on a string with a newline after "S2=2.\n" and this did not work, it only pulled before the new line.

Comment: I tried the actual answer here, it did not work correctly, is it possible that it is not a true new line character?  I've edited my question to provide another example.

Comment: @JM: Your input data as pasted also contains a *space* char. after each `\n`. If it's acceptable to simply remove all spaces, too, simply add a space to `tr -d '\n'`, i.e.: `tr -d '\n '`.

Comment: @JM: Glad to hear it; quick tip for examining input data: pipe to `od -a` or `od -c` - it'll show byte-byte representations with control characters represented symbolically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), read the whole file in slurp mode, remove newline characters and search it using a regular expression:

```
perl -0777 -nE '
  $_ = join q||, split /\n/; 
  printf qq|%s\n|, $1 if m/\\S2=([\d.]+)/
' infile
```

It yields:

```
8.75446
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible using just bash, though this won't work so well for very large files.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
string=$(<"test.txt")
var=$(echo $string) # word-splitting will replace each newline with a space here

while IFS= read -r word; do
  [[ $word =~ '\S2='([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)'\'  ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done <<< "$var"
```

e.g.

```
> ./abovescript 
8.75446
```

Comment: Efficiency issues aside, you could simplify your approach to the following: `IFS= read -d '' -r fileContents <"test.txt"; [[ $fileContents =~ '\S2='([0-9]*\.[0-9]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`. This reads the entire file as is into variable `$fileContents`, then matches against it.
Also note, however, that the OP said that the newlines could be *anywhere*, so the safer approach is really to *remove* all newlines before matching.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `gnu awk` version (due to `RS` with multiple characters):

```
awk -F'\' 'NR==2 {print $1}' RS="S2=" file
8.75446
```

---

A version that works with most `awk`

```
awk -F\\ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/S2=/) {split($i,a,"=");print a[2]}}' file
8.75446
```